# subversion (svn) from command line: any single command to "reflect all the changes"?

Tags: svn, maven, maven-plugin

When you  work at a project, at least myself, either if you are using an IDE (like eclipse or netbeans) or not, you update source files, create directories, create new files, remove some files, or rename them. (I don't want spend time issuing svn commands for every single file, even more if some of them, maybe, are not yet final).

At some moment, you think you've got it: alright, this is what I want to keep and save into the repository.

Is there any single svn command to say "store the working project as it is now"?
(this may imply a large set of adds and removes (a rename = local copy with svn remove+add) and recursing into directories).

If not (as I guess), any shell script to do this task? (based on svn status, recursively for each subfolder).

**update:**

Is there any maven plugin to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow. `svn ci` at the root of your working copy (or at the highest level that makes sense) *does* what you're describing. If your IDE has a Subversion plugin (both Eclipse and Netbeans do), that plugin should be handling your renames, moves, etc. behind the scenes so you don't have to manually `svn mv`.

Comment: @alroc Hopefully, but for instance: 1. `rm main.c` (shell command, remove an early committed file) 2. `svn status` ( ! main.c) 3. `svn ci` (no output) 4. `svn status` (still ! main.c) and if in a separate directory you do `checkout`, then you still get `main.c`

Comment: Then you're deleting `main.c` wrong. If you want it removed from Subversion, it's `svn rm main.c` (again, your IDE's plugin should be doing this for you). If it was an accidental delete from the shell, you can get it back with `svn up`.

Comment: @alroc But I don't want to issue an `svn command` for each change in the working project. I only want to store all the files with only one command as a big snapshot.

Comment: Again, if you're working with an IDE, its Subversion plugin should do this for you. Otherwise, you can probably twist `svn_load_dirs.pl` into doing what you want.  But really, you're going to find this with *any* VCS - to make changes to the working copy, you have to use the client to *tell* the underlying data structures that those changes are being made. Is it really that much of a burden to use `svn rm` vs. `rm`? It's only 4 extra keystrokes.

Comment: @arloc No, it is not so difficult. But perhaps one might forget prefixing with `svn`, some `cp`, `rm`, orders; and when you create a file you don't use `svn vi a.txt`, so you have to remeber `svn add a.txt` later. That's why I think it is musch easier to say "store all".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does the task:

```
if [ $# != 1 ]
then
    echo  "usage: doSVNsnapshot.sh DIR"
    exit 0
fi

ROOT=$1

for i in `find ${ROOT} -type d \! -path "*.svn*" `
do

    echo
    echo "--------------------------"
    ( cd $i ; 
    echo $i
    echo "--------------------------"


    svn status | awk '  
            /^[!]/ { system("svn rm " $2) }
            /^[?]/ { system("svn add " $2) }
        '
    )
    echo

done
```